# Can't change resolution

Tags: nvidia, resolution

When I get to the log in screen everything is fine but when I log in the resolution completely changes to something else. I tried going into display to fix it but it says that my resolution is at the correct amount and when I try other resolutions they are even bigger. I'm using nvidia driver 304.88 and I'm assuming that my graphics card isn't fried because I can do every thing I used to at the same speed.

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the output of running in the terminal: `xrandr`, `lspci -nnk | grep -A6 VGA`, `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: @Braiam you want me to type those commands in terminal and say what I got from that? sorry I don't understand too much with computers.

Comment: @Paindeer yes, that's what he is saying. You can [edit] your question by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath the body of your post. Paste the output of those commands in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from OP](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/340973/2):

> It has been resolved I just had to go into NVIDIA X setting servers then from there click on X server display config and under the resolution tab click auto. If you don't have NVIDIA X setting server I have no idea what to do for you, but try to find one for your specific graphics card.